# Webcam+Audio broadcast to multiple users without flash using WebRTC with a server in the middle using PHP

Tags: php, webrtc

Since webrtc has a limit on the number of users a person can broadcast webcam to (due to bandband limitations of the user) I am looking for a sollution where in webRTC will broadcast to the server directly.

The server would accept the webrtc connection, and let the webRTC data stream to the server.

When a request is made for the webcam, through websockets, the server would just pas through the data it is getting from whe webRCT connection, preferrably with php

Questions:

a) Is it possible for PHP to accept a webRTC call, and let the data be streamed to the server?

b) Is is possible to display the webcam+audio data from the server, send through websockets(php) in HTML5  ?

c) Could you point me to where i would see an example of php accepting a webRTC call, and let it stream to the server

d) Would it be hard to display the data through the video tag or canvas, that is received from the websocket?

Or even better
Stream the webcam directly through the server with websockets
Playback the websocket data through html5

Maybe i should rephrase the entire question:

I have an audio recording example here:
http://www.smartjava.org/content/record-audio-using-webrtc-chrome-and-speech-recognition-websockets

Can this be used to record webcam too? (and stream it back to the user through canvas or video)

Comment: This has probably been solved somewhere else, but just in case... I'd suggest you have a look at [kurento](http://kurento.org), since it offers a WS port in the signalling plane, so you can use this port with php. There is even a [php client](https://github.com/rukavina/kurento-client-php) implemented by one contributor.